# Finding the basis of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm having a bit of trouble with Linear algebra and just trying to cram for exams. I'm currently looking at exam questions and came across these and I'm stumped any help would be really appreciated.

Find a basis for $ S = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x − y = 0\}.$

Find a basis for $ C = \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3: x = y − z\}.$

my line of thinking is that in the first one z is equal to zero and these questions would be done the same?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case any point $(x,y,z) $can be written as $(x,x,z)$, i.e, $$x(1,1,0)+z(0,0,1)$$.Therefore it's basis is (1,1,0) and (0,0,1).
Similarly in the second case, any point $(x,y,z)$ can be written as $(y-z,y,z)$, i.e, $$y(1,1,0)+z(-1,0,1)$$.And therefore basis in this case are (1,1,0) and (-1,0,1).I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, would you mind explaining why this is the case? how come it's only 1 and not 2?